# Get the product name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to be able to display a product title by using PHP to echo the product name by the product ID (this is to be displayed within a Page, not the product page itself). I am using Wordpress and I have a plugin for PHP so I can include PHP code using `[php]echo 'example';[/php]`

One product example is; http://ukcctvinstallations.co.uk/product/1-camera-residential-system-hi-res/

When I edit the product, you can see in the URL that the 'Post' = 129 so am I right in saying this is the product ID?

If anyone has a solution for this, that would be much appreciated. I am using WooCommerce.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found a solution:-

`echo get_the_title( 'ID' );`

Take a look here:
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/package-WooCommerce.Functions.Product.html

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: The code should be `echo get_the_title( $id );` where $id is the ID of the product, or for the current product in the theme loop, just use `echo get_the_title();`. If you are definitely wanting to echo it, you can simplify this to `the_title();` - no echo required.

Answer (score 55):

Assuming you get the product as an object

```
$product = wc_get_product( id );

echo $product->get_title();
```

(WC version 2.5.2)

Answer (score 18):

**2017 - 2020** - Since WooCommerce 3, use the `WC_Product` method `get_name()`

```
global $product;

// If the WC_product Object is not defined globally
if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}

echo $product->get_name();
```

On cart items:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    echo $cart_item['data']->get_name();
}
```

On Order items:

```
foreach( $order->get_items() as $cart_item ) {
    echo $item->get_name();
    // Or
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object
    echo $product->get_name();
}
```